# Connect list cells of two lists by using drag&drop and draw line between them

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I try to connect to list views by drag and drop so when i take a list cell from view 1
and drop ist onto a list cell in view 2 there should be a line drawn between those twit to reflect the connection.

What i try to accomplish should look something like this

[image: list to list connection]
So far i managed to add basic drag and drop support to the lists which work but the line part seems to be tricky.

In the moment i save the x/y coordinates of the mouse event when i start dragging in list view 1
by using this code but it´s not working for the correct drop coordinates

```
testdevice_list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TestDevice>, ListCell<TestDevice>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell call(ListView<TestDevice> param) {
        TestDeviceCell cell = new TestDeviceCell();
        cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
                        /*first try was to use event.getSceneX() but this didn´t work
                          now by using a method inside the custom cell seems to work better
                          to find the correct start point to draw line
                        */
            startX = cell.getStartX();
            startY = cell.getStartY();

                        /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
            System.out.println("onDragDetected");

            Dragboard db = testdevice_list.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.LINK);

                        /* put a string on dragboard */
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(testdevice_list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getTester_typ());
            db.setContent(content);

            event.consume();
        });
        cell.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                            /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
                System.out.println("onDragDone");
                            /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
                if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.LINK) {
                    stopX = ((PruefvorschriftListCell) event.getSource()).getStopX();
                    stopY = ((PruefvorschriftListCell) event.getSource()).getStopY();
                    //stopX = ((TestDeviceCell)event.getSource()).getLayoutX() - ((TestDeviceCell)event.getSource()).getHeight() / 2;
                    //stopY = ((TestDeviceCell)event.getSource()).getLayoutY() - ((TestDeviceCell)event.getSource()).getWidth()/ 2;

                    //stopX = event.getSceneX();
                    //stopY = event.getSceneY();
                    addConnection();
                    //testdevice_list.getItems().remove(testdevice_list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });
        return cell;
    }
});
```

the addConnection method just tries to draw a line

```
private void addConnection(){
    System.out.println("Drawing line");
    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setAbsolute(true);
    moveTo.setX(startX);
    moveTo.setY(startY);

    LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
    lineTo.setAbsolute(false);
    lineTo.setX(stopX);
    lineTo.setY(stopY);

    path.getElements().add(moveTo);
    path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    path.setStrokeWidth(5);
    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    drawRegion.getChildren().add(path);
}
```

Here are my question:

1. Why does it start drawing line in wrong place see picture
   [image: wrong coordinates]
2. How would i stick the line exactly to the green point (from point to point)?
3. How would i make it moveable when i scroll one list that the lines move on?

EDIT:
Here is the code of TestDeviceCell (just the important part):

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import protokollTool.model.TestDevice;

public class TestDeviceCell extends ListCell<TestDevice> {
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST_SERIAL_CLASS = "device-list-serial";
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST_ICON_CLASS = "device-list-icon";
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST_TYP_CLASS = "device-list-typ";
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST_GRID_CLASS = "device-list-grid";
    private static final String FONT_AWESOME = "FontAwesome";

    private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    private Label serial = new Label();
    private Label typ = new Label();
    private AnchorPane icon = new AnchorPane();
    private Circle circ = new Circle();

    private double startX =0;
    private double startY =0;


    public TestDeviceCell() {
        configureGrid();        
        configureIcon();
        configureCycle();
        configureTyp();
        configureSerial();
        addControlsToGrid();            
    }
    private void configureGrid() {
        grid.getStyleClass().add(DEVICE_LIST_GRID_CLASS);
    }

    private void configureIcon() {
        icon.setMinHeight(40);
        icon.setMinWidth(40);
        icon.getStyleClass().add(DEVICE_LIST_ICON_CLASS);
    }
    private void configureCycle() {
        circ.setRadius(10);
        circ.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        circ.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            setStartX(circ.getLayoutX());
            setStartY(circ.getLayoutY());
            System.out.println("X-Start:"+getStartX()+"-Y-Start:"+getStartY());
        });
    }

    private void configureSerial() {
        serial.getStyleClass().add(DEVICE_LIST_SERIAL_CLASS);
    }

    private void configureTyp() {
        typ.getStyleClass().add(DEVICE_LIST_TYP_CLASS);
    }

    private void addControlsToGrid() {
        grid.add(icon, 0, 0, 1, 2);                    
        grid.add(serial, 1, 0);        
        grid.add(typ, 1, 1);
        grid.add(circ, 1, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(TestDevice dev, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(dev, empty);
        if (empty) {
            clearContent();
        } else {
            addContent(dev);
        }
    }

    private void clearContent() {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    private void addContent(TestDevice dev) {
        setText(null);
        serial.setText(dev.getTester_name());
        typ.setText(dev.getTester_typ());
        setStyleClassDependingOnTyp(dev);        
        setGraphic(grid);
    }

    private void setStyleClassDependingOnTyp(TestDevice dev) {
        icon.getStyleClass().remove(dev.getTester_typ());
        icon.getStyleClass().add(dev.getTester_typ());
    }

    public double getStartX() {
        return startX;
    }

    public void setStartX(double startX) {
        this.startX = startX;
    }

    public double getStartY() {
        return startY;
    }

    public void setStartY(double startY) {
        this.startY = startY;
    }
}
```

The other ListCell class (PruefvorschriftListCell) is the same as TestDeviceCell except the
following function:

```
private void configureCycle() {
    circ.setRadius(10);
    circ.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    circ.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
        setStopX(event.getSceneX());
        setStopY(event.getSceneY());
        System.out.println("X-Stop:"+getStopX()+"-Y-Stop:"+getStopY());
    });
}
```

Thx
Inge

Comment: ... and your question?

Comment: You'll need to show the cell implementation, or at least the getStartX/Y and getStopX/Y methods.

Comment: Any help would be great. I'm a bit stuck.